# Samba won't copy the .pulse file

Tags: samba

I'm using Linux and Samba. Samba doesn't seem to create the symbolic links to allow file transfers from root such as the `.pulse` file and its contents. Is there a way to configure Samba to do this?

When I try to copy this file over (while in root) I get the following error:

> cp: cannot create symbolic link 'mnt/Test Folder for Samba/.pulse/e13f3864bc5706771f61b8dd00000445-runtime': Operation not supported

I also tried  editing the smb.conf file in the Global section with the following:

```
wide links = yes
unix extensions = no
follow symlinks = yes
```